# How to iterate through column names and and do the same procedure on each column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I currently have two large dataframes which I will condense for the purpose of this questions.  Dataframe 1 has a list of probesets and transcripts.  I must match the transcripts to the corresponding transcripts in dataframe 2 and get the data for each subjet as you can see below:

```
       Probeset       Transcript
0    1554784_at  ENST00000547702
1           NaN  ENST00000547849
2     212983_at  ENST00000311189
3           NaN  ENST00000397596
4  1566643_a_at  ENST00000587894
```

and then the following dataframe where I need to match the transcripts:

```
     transcript_id  phchp230v2  phchp273v3  phchp367v3  phchp201v2
0  ENST00000547702    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
1  ENST00000547849    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
2  ENST00000311189    0.336418    0.044721    0.155847    1.676620
3  ENST00000397596    0.027106    0.016806    0.014509    0.022015
4  ENST00000587894    0.048200    0.089618    0.046528    0.000000
```

What I need to do is match the transcripts that are in dataframe 1 with the transcripts in dataframe 2 and get the data that is in each transcript for that specific subject that is at the top of dataframe 2. However, there is a lot of data in each of these so I would have to search for the transcripts and the corresponding data for that transcript as they are in just in order how I showcased.  The expected output is as shows:

```
       Probeset       Transcript  phchp230v2  phchp273v3  phchp367v3  phchp201v2
0    1554784_at  ENST00000547702    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
1           NaN  ENST00000547849    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
2     212983_at  ENST00000311189    0.336418    0.044721    0.155847    1.676620
3           NaN  ENST00000397596    0.027106    0.016806    0.014509    0.022015
4  1566643_a_at  ENST00000587894    0.048200    0.089618    0.046528    0.000000
```

I'm not sure how to go about finding the transcripts and then placing the specific data found with the correct subject headers as well, thank you all in advance!

Comment: groupby the two dataframes on "Transcript" column. df1.groupby(df2, how="left", on = 'Transcript')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge them by [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), as follows:

(Assuming the first/second dataframes are called `df1`/`df2` respectively)

```
df_out = df1.merge(df2.rename({'transcript_id': 'Transcript'}, axis=1), on='Transcript', how='left')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)


       Probeset       Transcript  phchp230v2  phchp273v3  phchp367v3  phchp201v2
0    1554784_at  ENST00000547702    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
1           NaN  ENST00000547849    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
2     212983_at  ENST00000311189    0.336418    0.044721    0.155847    1.676620
3           NaN  ENST00000397596    0.027106    0.016806    0.014509    0.022015
4  1566643_a_at  ENST00000587894    0.048200    0.089618    0.046528    0.000000
```